# reading java class files using java program

Tags: java, io, byte, fileinputstream

I am writing a java code to help me read and print all byte code in a `.class` file.

I have tried surfing the internet, but the answers dont really answer my question.
below is the code I currently have based on some help I found on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

```
private static void readByte ( )
{
     Path file = Paths.get("bin/com/reading/frombyte/ReadFourBytes.class");          
     try {
         byte[] myBytes = Files.readAllBytes(file);
         for(byte b : myBytes)
             System.out.println((char)b);
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Basically I want to interpret these `bytes` into human-readable characters.

thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain more clearly (a) What your code should do; and (b) What is is currently doing.

Comment: Sounds like you need a [disassembler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler)/[decompiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler).

Comment: bytecode is not at all human readable, i think you want to decompile it?

Comment: Are you trying to develop a decompiler program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this command will help you:

```
javap -verbose -c -private ReadFourBytes
```